# Using nohup or similar, can I include the command/query that was run to generate the output in nohup?

Tags: linux, nohup

I have a hive query that I can run using nohup e.g. `nohup hive -i my_query.hive > nohup.out 2>&1 &`

This results in the output of running the hive query contained within my_query.hive in the file nohup.out.

My question is, is there someway to include the input that was used so that this single file, in this case nohup.out contains the hive query being called via my_query.hive along with the output?

Answer (score 1):

The following command should do the trick:

```
(cat my_query.hive; echo "") > nohup.out && nohup hive -i my_query.hive >> nohup.out
```

Comment: Thanks this appears to be running but it does not detach the process from my terminal. Do I just add & to the end?

Comment: Actually I'm going to delete and repost. Thank you for the tip nonetheless